# Autoload Error Files Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an `error_codes.php` file located in `application/libraries` I have it autoloaded when CodeIgniter loads but the variables are not recognized in the controllers. I get an undefined variable when loading the page. Am I loading the files wrong or do I have the variables wrong. I have tried it wihtout the `static` but no luck.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class error_codes {

    static $a200 = array('error' => 'NO', 'code' => '200', 'description' => 'none', 'message' => 'Request ok');
    static $a206 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '206', 'description' => 'Partial Content', 'message' => 'Not enough location data!');
//    
    static $a400 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '400', 'description' => 'Bad Request', 'message' => 'This is not a valid URL');
    static $a401 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '401', 'description' => 'Unauthorized', 'message' => 'Did you provide valid API key?');
    static $a402 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '402', 'description' => 'Username Exists', 'message' => 'Username already exists!');
    static $a403 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '403', 'description' => 'No User Exists', 'message' => 'User does not exists!');
    static $a404 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '404', 'description' => 'Invalid Parameters', 'message' => 'Not enough user parameters!');
    static $a406 = array('error' => 'YES', 'code' => '406', 'description' => 'Invalid Email', 'message' => 'Email is invalid!');

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use static variables this way. Convert them to public vars, this might do what you want.

Additionally run your code with a step-debugger and see if your file gets included.

Comment: The file is being loaded, I have changed them to 'public' and I call the variable using '$this->a200' for example. This still gives me an Undefined Variable.

Comment: If you don't use aliasing, you should access them as `$this->error_codes->a200`.

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little new to CodeIgniter. It works as attended.